# Show that the ideal $(2,f(x)) \subset \mathbb Z[x]$ is maximal for a given condition.

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

Let $\phi_2 : \mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z_2[x]$ defined by $\phi_2(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\bar a_i}x^i$, where $\bar {a_i} :=a_i \ mod \ 2.$

> Show that the ideal of the form $(2,f(x)) \subset \mathbb Z[x]$ such that $\phi_2(f(x))$ is irreducible are maximal ideals.

How can I show it?

Basically if we get a onto homomorphism from $\mathbb Z[x] $ to a field whose kernel is $(2,f(x))$  then it must be maximal ideal. Otherwise we have to show applying definition.

Please someone give some hints.

Thank you..

Comment: If $I$ is such an ideal, what can you say about $\phi_2(I) = (\phi_2 f)$?

Comment: How many elements do you think this field has?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown are you saying about the field $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: @anomaly here $\phi_2(I)$ becomes maximal in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ but from  here how can we say that $I$ is maximal..Please give some little hints. more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint:*** $$\mathbb{Z}[x] \xrightarrow{\phi_2} \mathbb{Z}_2[x]\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(\phi_2(f(x))).$$
Here $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(\phi_2(f(x)))$ is the natural quotient map.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal $I$ is maximal in commutative ring $R$ if and only if $R/I$ is a field.

We have $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,f(x))\cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(\phi_2(f(x))).$  Can you finish?